# How do I solve a under-determined quadratic multi-variate system?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, bayesian, monte-carlo

I have the following equation:

$$
Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \beta_3 X_3 + \beta_{11} X_{1}^2 + \beta_{22} X_{2}^2 + \beta_{33} X_{3}^2 + \beta_{12} X_{1} X_{2} + \beta_{23} X_{2} X_{3} + \beta_{31} X_{3} X_{1}
$$

I know the values of all $\beta$s.

I have following constraints:

$$
X_1 = N(\mu_1, \sigma_1) \\
X_2 = N(\mu_2, \sigma_2) \\
X_3 = N(\mu_3, \sigma_3)
$$

$X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ are independent of each other and are Gaussian distributed.

I am not looking for optimizing the $Y$ value, but just solve the above equation for known values of $Y$ and $\beta$s to find $X_i$s.

I know about the Langrange's multipliers method but I am not using it right now because I think it is for optimization. Am I wrong?

Is there a method similar to Monte Carlo method for Ordinary Least Squares for Quadratic equations?

I am sorry if there is some confusion in the post as Maths/Stats is not my major strength. Please comment for additional information if needed.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you have the data points $(y,x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and are asking which $\beta_{\cdot}$ were used to make them work?

Comment: @gt6989b Sorry! Please check now.

Comment: How many data points do you have available? I also don't understand how knowing the distributions of the $X_i$ will help for anything...

Comment: I believe you are asking about the data points of $X_i$s. It is continuous distribution.